# Why is my blockchain.com not receiving bitcoin?

Tags: blockchain

I created a wallet on blockchain.com, copied the address from the '' bictoin request '', sent it to the person, and that person sent me a bitcoin after a few hours.
After a few hours my laptop restarted. When I logged in again, the Bitcoin address was different.
Bitcoin was sent to that address, but my wallet no longer recognizes the address it generated.

Can I recover the amount of bitcoin? What can I do?

Answer (score 1):

**Your bitcoins are not lost.**

What you observed is completely normal behavior which one would experience across most wallets. The wallet generates a new address once it detects that you have received coins on the previous address. This is done to minimize address-reuse which improves the privacy of the sender and the receiver.

This has nothing to do with your laptop restarting.

Comment: Yes, but I did not get the amount of bitcoin, and I do not find the address I was supposed to get the bitcoin at the addresses I used.
And the address generated by the wallet that I received bitcoin, I can not find it in my wallet.

Comment: I'm not sure if I understand you correctly. Are you sure the other person send coins to you? Did they arrive at the "request-bitcoin"-address you send the person?

Comment: I used the "bitcoin address request" to get a bitcoin, I used a proxy, and after a few hours the proxy expired and my laptop has restarted, I used athoer  IP, and IP changed and I logged back into my wallet, it generated another address bitcoin request, and the funds received on the previously generated address are no longer recognized by my wallet.

Comment: https://www.blockchain.com/btc/address/13D6FEsc8oJ4ynJD7hL52CM1GPzKp8YZh4 , this is adress generated first time, and the btc is there..

Comment: block explorer shows that the funds arrived at the address specified as expected, but the transaction does not appear in my Blockchain wallet’s transaction history.